# adding the loop value to the forecast data generated in for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm creating a forecast on different product groups using the for loop and I would like to store the loop value (the different product groups) in the forecast data sets created in the loop.

The different data sets are stored in a list.

```
# Creating data set for looping
library(dplyr)
prdgrp <- as.vector(mth3['MMITCL'])
prdgrp %>% distinct(MMITCL) 

mth3$TPC_MTD2 <- mth3$TPC_MTD + 0.000001
tail(mth3)

# List for storing the data being created in the loop
additive <- list()

#START LOOP
for (i in 1:length(unique(prdgrp$MMITCL)))
{
mth31 <- ts(mth3[mth3$MMITCL == unique(prdgrp$MMITCL)[i], c("TPC_MTD2")], frequency=12, start=c(2012,1), end=c(2017,1)) 

library(forecast)
abe  <- hw(mth31, h= 2, seasonal="additive")
abe$z <- eval(parse(text=i), abe)
additive[[i]]<- abe
}
```

I cannot get the `abe$z <- eval(parse(text=i), abe)` to work, any ideas.

The additive data looks like this:

```
[[24]]
         Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80     Lo 95    Hi 95
Feb 2017       533.1243 260.2218 806.0268 115.75597 950.4927
Mar 2017       430.8104 155.7259 705.8950  10.10498 851.5159

[[25]]
         Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80     Lo 95    Hi 95
Feb 2017       244.7862 114.0818 375.4906  44.89103 444.6813
Mar 2017       327.1901 196.2669 458.1133 126.96038 527.4198
```

I would like to get the id's ([[24]]) into a column. So it would look like this:

```
[[24]]
         Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80     Lo 95    Hi 95  Name
Feb 2017       533.1243 260.2218 806.0268 115.75597 950.4927  24
Mar 2017       430.8104 155.7259 705.8950  10.10498 851.5159  24

[[25]]
         Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80     Lo 95    Hi 95  Name
Feb 2017       244.7862 114.0818 375.4906  44.89103 444.6813  25
Mar 2017       327.1901 196.2669 458.1133 126.96038 527.4198  25
```

Running `class(additive)` returns a `"forecast"`

Comment: Your `i` is of class `integer`, `eval(parse())` expects `character`.

Comment: You are probably must use deparse-substitute. Try: `abe$z <- deparse(substitute(i))`.

Comment: @r.user.05apr - I tried your suggestion but without luck. I did add some more info in the question text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer based on input from @r.user.05apr:

```
additive[[i]] <- data.frame(
    ProdGrp = eval(parse(text=i)),
    Value= hw(mth31, h= 2, seasonal="additive")$mean
```